# Alamofire - Modify Request object after creation

Tags: ios, http-headers, request, alamofire

**Short :** Is there any way to modify the backed `NSURLRequest` (headers, body, or other) of the `Request` object after it has been created ?

**Long :** I have a custom `Manager` with `startRequestsImmediately` set to `false`. If my access token is currently being refreshed, all requests are waiting for refresh to finish, then they are resume.
Of course, I need to modify theirs HTTP headers to update access token before resuming them.

I can't just track directly `NSURLRequest`s then recreating `Request`s object because I need to keep all completion closure previously set for those requests.

Is anyone find a way to do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RequestAdapter](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#adapting-and-retrying-requests). Example:

```
class MyAdapter: RequestAdapter {
    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest
        urlRequest.setValue("Bar", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Foo")
        return urlRequest
    }
}

// Then...

let manager = SessionManager()
manager.adapter = MyAdapter()

manager.request("https://httpbin.org/get")
```